# Save form with repeater fields with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms, repeater

I have a form in `html` where the user can add as many members as needed.

So I have a div with the members' details :

```
<div class="form-group form-group-100 clearfix">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="namemember">
//..........
</div>
```

And a button to add a new member:

```
<button id="b1" class="btn add-more" type="button">Add Member +</button>
```

This the `jquery` code to add a new member:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var member=jQuery('.form-group-100').html();
  jQuery(".add-more").click(function(e){
    alert('A New Member Added');
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.form-group-100').after("<div class="+""+"form-group-100"+"clearifx"+">"+member+"</div>");
  });
});
```

And this the `jquery` code to send data via `ajax`:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Custom From submistion ADD NEW
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#addnew').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = $('.myform').serialize();
      var url = window.location.href;
      data += "&url=" + url;

      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/save_team.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        complete: function (json) {
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(json.responseText);
        if (jsonData['msg'] == 'success') {
          alert("Success");
        } else {
          alert("Sorry! Something went wrong. Please try again.");
        }
      }
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
```

I know that if I had for example a fixed number of members I could read the data like this:

```
$_POST["namemember"];
```

But now how I can read the data passed when I have variable number of members? And how I can distinguish each member's details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array instead of singular name like

```
<input type="text" name="namemember[]">
```

And you can access it in PHP like:

```
$namemember = unserialize($_POST["namemember"]);
foreach( $namemember as $value ) {
 print $value;
}
```

as now `$_POST['namemember']` is an array of fields

Comment: You also may need $namemember = unserialize($_POST["namemember"]);

Comment: Now I can see in the posted form data (network tab in chrome) multiple "namember[]" values and not an array

Comment: @slon +1 thanks for the correction. I've made the edit to the post.

Comment: I get this error `Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` in line `$namemember = unserialize($_POST["namemember"]);`

Comment: Can you `print_r`  the content of of `$_POST["namemember"]` and share it with us here ?

Comment: Here : `Array ( [0] => asdadada [1] => asdsada [2] => asdadaa )`

Comment: Then its already an array, you don't need to unserialize it. Directly iterate it through PHP's `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

Do you store the information of the members in a BBDD?

If the answer is yes you can do a query to get all members and their details and have it in a variable.

Comment: I want to store them to the DB, but I dont know how to read the data passed from the form if there are repeated fields.

Comment: This could be in question comments section.

Comment: If every time you add a member you add a div for that member, just put all members into a general div and with a js function you can get that information into and object. @thelaw

Comment: Can you provide an example?